# $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ iff $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded above

Tags: real-analysis

As the statement says I am trying to prove or disprove it. I have proved the ($\Rightarrow$) part but I am struggling with the second part.

I am thinking the ($\Leftarrow$) part of the statement is true since if a sequence is not bounded it cannot converge, so if a sequence is not bounded above means it is not bounded so it makes sense the $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$$

I am trying to find a counterexample to potentially disprove it but I can not come up with anything concrete.

Comment: Think $(-1)^n \cdot n$.

Comment: Yeah, it is not true. It is true if $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence and unbounded above.

Comment: But what is true is $a_n\to \infty \implies \{a_n\}$ not bounded above (but not the other direction).  And what *else* is true is that if $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded above there is a  subsequence $\{b_n\}\subset \{a_n\}$ where $b_n\to \infty$.  ... To find a counter example to $\{a_n\}$ not bounded implies $a_n \to \infty$.  Take any unbounded sequence, say, $1,2,4,8,16,....,2^k,....$ and just seed in a bunch of smaller terms. say $1,0,2,0,4,8,16,0......,0,2^k,0,2^{k+1}, 0.....$ It's unbounded, sure, but not $\to \infty$ because every other term we keep getting *smashed* down to #@%& zero!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the sequence defined by
$$a_{2n}=n\text{ and } a_{2n+1}=0$$

$(a_n) $ is not bounded above because

$$(\forall M\in \Bbb R)\;(\exists p\in \Bbb N)\;:\; a_{2p}>M$$
where $ p=\lfloor|M|\rfloor+1$. But
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n \ne \infty$$
since
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{2n+1}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider what they mean.  $a_n \to \infty$ means for any large number $M$ there as poitn $N$ were all $a_{n; n > N} > M$. i.e. as you go along the terms eventually get big.  But $\{a_n\}$ not being bounded above just means there is no highest element. Which means every now and then there's an element larger than all previous. But it doesn't say anything about the other elements in general which need not get large at all.

So that rises the idea of a counter example. Imagine a sequence that always have a few small elements.. say $a_n =\begin{cases} 0&\text{if } n\text{ is even}\\??? &\text{if } n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$ where the odd positioned terms might have the unbounded big terms. say.....

$a_n =\begin{cases} 0&\text{if } n\text{ is even}\\n &\text{if } n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$

That's a counter example.